# I used a fake surname on my passport

Tags: filipino-citizens

I have a passport that has a Japanese surname (not my real surname). I applied for a new passport using my real husband's surname. Now my new passport is being held in the Department of Foreign Affairs (DFA)? Am I going to jail? Is there any possibility to get my new passport? Please I need help.

Comment: I rewrote the question to try to make it a little clearer. If I misunderstood, please undo/revert my edits or make your own.

Comment: How did you get the passport with a fake name in the first place?  Were you not required to show proof of identity with other documents?  If everything was faked, then yes they might be able to prosecute you for fraud (or some variation thereof).

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to jail.

It is common to change one's last name after marriage. If any question arises, you can show your legally notarized marriage certificate as evidence of the change of status.

Comment: Did you miss the title? It sounds like the OP was using a fake name and/or fake passport and now trying to get a legal one. That's a bit different than a name change after a marriage or divorce.

Comment: Considering that English is not the OP's native language, "fake" may not hold the same weight.

Comment: @Burhan good observation. The OP *could* (but probably doesn't) mean something like "I gave my name as Mary Jones, which is my 'official' name on all my other documents, but I really see myself as Princess Sparkle Henrietta Tiara XXVIII Her Elite Highness."